# How to use doctrine One-To-Many, Bidirectional?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I am making blog maker in symfony and doctrine

I am trying to connect, ID of row in blog posts with comments by blog_id value, but I getting this error

\Entity\BlogPosts.php

> The association App\Entity\BlogPosts#comments refers to the owning side field App\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments#blogId which is not defined as association, but as field.
>
> The association App\Entity\BlogPosts#comments refers to the owning side field App\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments#blogId which does not exist.

My actual code looks like this

\Entity\BlogPosts.php

```
class BlogPosts
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments", mappedBy="blogId")
     */
    private $comments;

    //...
}
```

\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments.php

```
class Fe_blog_comments
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\BlogPosts", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $blogId;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ORM\Column(type="integer")`, the column should be managed by `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

Comment: When I remove integer definition I still getting error Expected value of type "App\Entity\BlogPosts" for association field "App\Entity\Frontend\Blog\Fe_blog_comments#$blogId", got "integer" instead

Comment: Is your scheme up to date?

Comment: Yes it is up to date

Comment: Clear cache and so on. This should really be the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186637/discussion-between-marek-and-msphn).